# Right way to share a git repo over ssh

Tags: git, ssh

I'm using a box as a shared repo, and my team connects to it via **ssh**.

What I do is:

1. Create an empty git repository on the central machine `git init`
2. Then from each workstation do something like `git clone ssh://user@central-box/Users/user/Projects/my-project/.git/`

This works nice, but git keeps yelling at me every time I make a push something like this:

[image]

Is there a better way of sharing a repo **over ssh**.

**IMPORTANT:** I'm well aware of the existence of `gitosis` and tools like that, I do not want anything fancy. Just sharing a .git repo over ssh.

Thanks

Comment: In addition to the two answers below, for an existing repo look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7268560/671282

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On the host machine you should do

```
git init --bare
```

Because you don't need the actual files, just the repo.

If the warning message is on a FIRST push to a repo, and no one has touched it, do a

```
git push -f
```

Otherwise, this error means your branch scheme isn't correct. You should NOT be editing the branch origin/branchname. You want your own local branch called branchname, then when you are ready to check in your code you do

```
git commit
git pull
git push
```

And you will push from your local branchname to origin/branchname.

**Edit**

I would like to see the output of this command in your local repo:

```
git branch
```

You should not see the word origin or your server name anywhere in the output

Comment: Nope, `git branch` on my machine (not the "bare" repo) yields *master

Comment: Is there a way to "fix" the central box now that I've already created the repo without passing --bare as an argument? :S

Comment: Your local repo should have everything the remote repo does. Pull it down to make sure, then just blow away the repo, make a bare one, and push everything back up.

Comment: it work perfectly with `--bare` the only change I need to make was renaming origin to the path without the `.git` subfolder. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

In addition to bwawok's solution, you'll need to watch out for permission issues. By default, when git creates files on a user's behalf, their permissions are sourced from the user's umask and their group is set to the user's default group. For common umasks and default groups, this will break a shared repo, since such files will be unmodifiable by other users.

Fortunately, git can be configured to do the right thing in this situation: Take a look at the `--shared` option to `git init` (or the `core.sharedRepository` setting). The simplest option is probably `--shared=group`, which grants write access to all users in the "git" group.