# Change GIT repository to shared

Tags: git, bash

Git allows to create a shared repository amongs a group:

```
git --bare init --shared=group
```

However - how can I change already existing repository to shared? I don't want to re-git-init it.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242282/how-to-configure-an-existing-git-repo-to-be-shared-by-a-unix-group

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242282/how-to-configure-an-existing-git-repo-to-be-shared-by-a-unix-group/3242364#3242364

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to configure an existing git repo to be shared by a UNIX group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242282/how-to-configure-an-existing-git-repo-to-be-shared-by-a-unix-group)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-init#_options):

> #### --shared[=(false|true|umask|group|all|world|everybody|0xxx)]
>
> Specify that the git repository is to be shared amongst several users.
>   This allows users belonging to the same group to push into that repository.
>   When specified, the config variable "core.sharedRepository" is set so that
>   files and directories under `$GIT_DIR` are created with the requested
>   permissions. When not specified, git will use permissions reported by umask(2).

Therefore, in order to change the permission, [`chmod`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/chmod-invocation.html) everything to your liking, and [set the `core.sharedRepository` in git config](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration) accordingly:

```
git config core.sharedRepository true
```

Comment: tried this: "git config core.sharedRepository=group", but when I test "git config -l", the option does not seem to appear. How can I verify, that it is correctly set?

Comment: Create a new file with git (`rm file && git checkout file`), and make sure it have the proper permission (group can read).

Comment: The proper syntax is "git config core.sharedRepository true" -- no "=".

Answer (score 11):

To make a private bare repo group shared:

1. Edit config and add `sharedRepository = group` to the `core` section
2. Fix permissions from inside the repo:

   - `chgrp -R target-group .`
   - `find . -type d | xargs chmod g+ws`
   - `find refs -type f | xargs chmod g+w`

Comment: Very bad answer.... `sharedRepository = mygroup` returns `remote: fatal: bad numeric config value 'mygroup' for 'core.sharedrepository': invalid unit` and none of those `chmod`s are fixing permissions.

Comment: It says `sharedRepository = group`, *not* `sharedRepository = mygroup`, i.e., this is not the group you are using, but always `group`.  The group you are using is `target group` in the example.  These commands surely work on any Unix-like OS if you run them with sufficient privileges.

Comment: Doing `--shared` seems to also add this to my config:  `[receive] denyNonFastforwards = true`.  I'm assuming it is a good idea to also add this manually when converting an existing repository to shared.