# trouble reverting to previous tags in GIT

Tags: git

## Background

I'm new to git, and I'm testing it as a version control for a website that is not hosted on github. I have made the `public_html` a git repo and created a bare repo outside the `public_html` that I push all the commits and tags to. My goal is to be able to tag changes I make to the website and have the option to quickly revert back to previous versions when desired. So far with my testing, I have been able to accomplish this by either using `reset` or `checkout` followed by the tag name to go back to previous versions.

## The Problem

I encounter problems when I make new version tags that involve removing files from a previous tag. If I try to `reset` to or `checkout` the previous tag where the files were once present and functional, visit requests for these pages return "Internal server error".  I know the files are there because I see them reappear in the `public_html` folder (as seen when refreshing cpanel, or filezilla). If I download these files, delete git from my website altogether, and add them back to the `public_html` folder, they work fine, indicating the files have not been modified or corrupted. Furthermore, when at a tag where the files are indeed removed, I get a "Page not found" result.

Is this a common issue? Any tips, advice, or workarounds would be much appreciated.

## Update 1

Based on the kind suggestions of @VonC, I have tried

1. Preventing unwanted EOL changes by setting the `core.autocrlf` to `FALSE`.
2. Running `git clean`.

Unfortunately, these suggestions did not resolve the issue. I have also determined that this issue happens with PHP files but not HTML. I have continued reading up on my own, but I've not yet found any reports of a similar issue. I hope to figure this out soon. Currently, I would be unable to revert to a previous version if I ended up removing files and regretting it, which is essentially one of the primary benefits I hope to get from git.

Also, I was curious if git modifies permissions, but I've checked, and they're unchanged.

## Update 2

I thought it might be helpful if I specified everything I tried in case someone wants to attempt recreating the problem.

```
$git init --bare bare_repo.git
$cd public_html
$git init
$git remote add origin ../bare_repo.git
$git add index.html # simple testing only "hello world" 
$git add commit -m "index.html"
$git tag -a v001 -m "v001"
$git push origin master --tags
```

Now add in a PHP file:

```
$git add phpinfo.php # again for testing only, includes <?php  phpinfo(); ?>
$git add index.html  #file changed to include link to phpinfo.php
$git commit -m "phpinfo.php"
$git tag -a v002 -m "v002"
$git push origin master --tags
```

Now, checkout `v001`:

```
 $git checkout v001
```

The *index.html* returns back to origin state without link, and *phpinfo.php* disappears from the `public_html` folder.

Now, checkout `v002`:

```
  $git checkout v002
```

The *index.html* regains link, and *phpinfo.php* re-appears in `public_html`.

However, when I try to go to *phpinfo.php*, I get the "Internal server error or misconfiguration" page load.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem had to do with GIT modifying permissions after checkout or reset operations. It changes the files from 664 to 644, which enables group writing. Although I had considered permission changes I had missed that this was happening. This happens with both HTML and PHP files, but it only manifested as a problem for PHP files. A quick search suggests solutions exist for this problem, so its just an issue of picking the best approach. Thanks @VonC for taking the time to consider my issue.

Comment: Good catch. +1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/7268608/6309 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/10516406/6309 might have helped.

Answer (score 0):

Try a stricter way to reset or checkout:

```
git reset --hard anOldTag
git clean -fd
```

Adding **[`git clean`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean)** would hep make sure the resulting working tree only include files from the SHA1 (here a tag) reset or checked out.
Be sure to test it out forst in a separate site, in order to validate it does not remote too much file!

Comment: Thank you for responding to my question. Unfortunately this did not work.

Comment: @joe5 try again after typing, on the server, git config --global core.autocrlf false. (done as the account running  the web server). Do so on the client side as well (as your account wokring on those file). Try again the all delete git, add them back. Then see if the issue persists on future checkouts.

Comment: Thanks for your follow up. I tried this, but unfortunately I still have the same issue. Interestingly, I find it is specific to php files, but does not occur with HTML files.